# Hide other unnecessary wallets from modal (leave only one we need)

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

Is it possible to leave only one wallet we need in modal from which we choose wallets? Currently it looks like this, but in chrome it still detects and shows other wallets like Phantom and etc.

```
const wallets = useMemo(
() => [
  new SolflareWalletAdapter({ network }),
],
[network],
```

);

Comment: We automatically detect wallets that implement the wallet standard API, and also MWA wallets on Android. We want to avoid apps having to include adapters in their own code as much as possible. Could you explain why you only want Solflare to be detected? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but might be able to give a suggestion if I understand a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

```
const WalletContextProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
const network = web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet')
const wallets = useMemo(() =>
    [
        //new walletAdapterWallets.PhantomWalletAdapter({network}),
        new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
    ]
    , [network])

return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={network}>
        <WalletProvider wallets={wallets}>
            <WalletModalProvider>
                {children}
            </WalletModalProvider>
        </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
)};
export default WalletContextProvider
```

> I am doing this and this is working on chrome as well